# Mobile AR – Scaling, Rotating and Dragging 3D Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality, ar-foundation, leantween

I am developing a mobile ar application for Android and iOS with Unity and AR Foundation. My current task is to implement the features scaling, rotating and dragging for 3d objects in the scene. While doing research I came across two ways – using [XRI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@2.5/manual/index.html) or [LeanTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595).

I tried XR Interaction Toolkit, but right know I am stuck at [one issue you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905317/xr-interaction-toolkit-events-are-not-thrown). So in the meantime I am going to try, will be LeanTween. Even if that doesn't completely convince me, because I don't want any more third-party dependencies.

Do you know any other possibilities in that case? What about implementing those by yourself? The dragging behavior is easy for me to implement, I would just orient the position to either the horizontal or vertical environment (planes from plane detection). But I couldn’t imagine doing the scaling and rotation in a good and intuitive way by using just fingers without any ui elements like extra buttons.

Is there any other way you know for those features?